# Odoo I want to add a tree view inside a wizard

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-11

I want to add a tree view inside my wizard.I tried like this:

```
<record id="view_immediate_transfer" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">xn_quotation_creation_wiz2</field>
        <field name="model">xn_quotation_creation_wiz</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Warning">
                <group>
                 <field name = "xn_customer_id" />
                </group>
                <group>
                <tree editable = "top">
                    <group>
                        <field name="product"/>
                        <field name="qty"/>
                    </group>
                </tree>
                </group>

                <footer>
                    <button name="save_button" string="Save" type="object" class="btn-primary"/>                
                 </footer>
            </form>
        </field>
```

But the fields given in tree view are showing like a form view.What to do..?
(I want to populate this fields from product master.)
[image]

> Python

```
class QuotationCreation2(models.TransientModel):
    _name = "xn_quotation_creation_wiz"

     xn_customer_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner',string = "Customer")
     product=fields.Many2one('product.product',string='Product')
     qty=fields.Integer(string='Quantity')
```

Comment: Verify the documentation, before asking simple questions.

Comment: @Navi Sorry bro some doubts while using it with wizard.

Comment: No issues, But try to do on your own before asking, just a friendly advice.

Comment: Ok bro..... @Navi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view definition is missing the related field you want to show as a tree inside the wizard, for example a `One2many` or `Many2many` field.

```
<field name="product_master">
  <tree editable = "top">
    <group>
      <field name="product"/>
      <field name="qty"/>
    </group>
  </tree>
</field>
```

Transient model is basically same as regular model, difference is that transient models is not persistent in the database, hence used for creating wizards. For any `tree` view within `form`, you need a relation of `One2many` or `Many2many` type.

```
class QuotationCreation2(models.TransientModel):
  _name = "xn_quotation_creation_wiz"

  xn_customer_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner',string = "Customer")
  product_master = fields.One2many('xn_quotation_creation_wiz.line','wiz_id')

class QuotationCreationLine(models.TransientModel):
  _name = "xn_quotation_creation_wiz.line"

  wiz_id = fields.Many2one('xn_quotation_creation_wiz.line')
  product=fields.Many2one('product.product',string='Product')
  qty=fields.Integer(string='Quantity')
```

Comment: Python is added in the question I have some doubts declaring one2many feild in a Transient Model.Please show me an eg: using the above code.

Comment: check now @vbt.